# Get live feed of rows inserted in table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table that's getting about 100 new rows every second. It's no problem because inserting is very fast, partly because there are no indexes in the table.

I cannot make time consuming lookups in the table, because it would risk blocking or slowing down the insertion of rows in the table.

I would like to get a live or almost live feed in my application of all the data inserted in the table. What would be a good way, if any, to get this information into my application.

Let me clarify what I mean by telling a not very good way of doing it. Every second I could execute this every second, adjusting the date comparison each time.

```
select * from MyTable where Date > '2015-12-22 22:50'
```

Date is not indexed in order to ensure fast insertion and even if it was indexed, I would be worried it doesn't perform well enough.

So instead I'm hoping for some way to hook in and get each insert as it's being inserted instead of having to look it up.

Comment: It's probably easier to have your writers dump the data into a queue which your 'live feed' service can read instead of trying to make the db do something rather backwards (without indexing)

Comment: Agree with @pvg. It doesn't seem like a good idea to give that db another task like this, especially since whatever is writing to it seems like a much more logical way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at `CDC` and `ChangeTracking` feature of SqlServer.

Comment: Sounds like you have an XY problem. If you want to use a database as real time IPC, then you really should be looking at an ESB instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do it with polling there is a decent solution to it.
There are two parts to the solution.

1. Let Sql Server notify you that the data table has changed
2. Get exactly the rows which are changed (or even the cells which have been updated).

**Part 1: SqlDependency**

[Create a `SqlDependency` on your database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by that SqlServer will let you know of updates via `SqlNotification`. Now the problem with `SqlDependency` is that it can only tell you that something has changed, but not what has changed. Solution to this problem is Part 2. Part 1 is described in diagram below (where `SqlNotifier` is a class created by me).

[image]

**Part 2: Change Tracking**

There is a very nice feature called [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx), which gives you exact rows which are added or deleted. Diagram below shows a class `SqlReceiver` (created by me). How it works is: your application and the Sql database both keep track of version number on which they are in. So for example when you receive a notification from Sql Server via `SqlNotifier` described in Part 1 (see Red Arrow on top in diagram), your application will send the version on which it currently is (v100)(middle red arrow). Database compares it to the version on which itself it (v105) and database will send exactly the rows which have been changed between version 100 and 105 (bottom red arrow). Problem solved.

[image]

If you read before, I mentioned that only added and deleted rows can be obtained via Change Tracking. If you need the data which has been updated then you have to use [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) along with Change Tracking to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that I do not need **Part 1** since it seems unneccessary to get notified 100 times per second. But if I'm reading it right, it seems **Part 2** can be used by itself and is designed exactly for the scenario I describe. Only downside is it's only available in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Nope, its available since Sql Server 2008 R2, so go ahead and plug it. And you may need Part1 only in the case when your data pumping is going to stay idle. If you say its always going to pump 100 records, then you don't need that. With that said, it doesn't necessarily bug you 100 times/sec. There is a event called `OnChange` which you have to subscribe after every message received, so you may choose to subscribe it  every half a second.